# Can't Export string made with StringForm?

Tags: export, string-manipulation, hold

This works. It returns "acb".

```
StringForm["a``b", "c"]
```

This doesn't work.

```
Export["test.txt", StringForm["a``b", "c"]]
```

Rather than "acb", `test.txt` contains the literal expression ``` StringForm["a``b", "c"] ```.

This doesn't work either - it's the same result.

```
Export["test.txt", Evaluate[StringForm["a``b", "c"]]]
```

How can I force Mathematica to perform the `StringForm`?

Comment: Could try `Export["test.txt", ToString @ StringForm["a``b", "c"]]`, but things will get ugly very quickly if the second argument of StringForm has things like 1/2 or 1.2*^-6.

Comment: I think `StringTemplate` is a better choice in this case.

Comment: @xzczd I personally don't like `StringTemplate`, e.g., things like ``StringTemplate["first `a` then `b`"][<|"a"->1/2, "b"->1.2*^-77|>]`` produce output that I consider very suboptimal.

Comment: @carl-woll Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, `ToString[StringForm[a,b]]` seems to behave very strangely if `b` contains newlines (which my use case does). E.g. I'd expect `ToString[StringForm["AAA\`\`BBB", "CCC\nDDD"]]` to return "AAACCC\nDDDBBB", but it actually returns "AAACCCBBB\n\ \ \ DDD". (Wrong letter order, extra whitespace.) `StringForm["AAA\`\`BBB", "CCC\nDDD"]` alone behaves as expected.

Comment: @ppm That's the same issue as I mentioned with 1/2 or 1.2*^-6. If you are only dealing with strings, then you can do: `First@ToBoxes@StringForm["AAA``BBB", "CCC\nDDD"]`

Comment: `Export["test.txt",First@ToBoxes@StringForm["AAA``BBB","CCC\nDDD"]]` writes a file with the literal string `"AAACCC\nDDDBBB"` (quotes and backslash-n included). Anyway, I was able to solve my problem by using <> instead of StringForm. But thanks for your help!